# How to adjust the text divs position automatically if one of them is removed from the top or the middle?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've written the following code which creates text divs upon typing and pressing enter, or copying pasting multiline text from somewhere. But the problem is if I remove a text div from the middle, the other text divs (the below ones) don't adjust their position automatically.

For example if I have the following text divs:

salt box
salt cellar
salt container
salt keeper
salt holder

If I delete the text div 'salt container', the divs below it won't adjust their position automatically to make for the gap left by the deleted div. I hope you guys understand what I mean.

Here's the snippet:

```js
// Function to create a new textDiv and add it to the container
function createTextDiv(text) {
  if (text.trim() != "") {
    var textDiv = $("<div class='textDiv'></div>").text(text.trim());
    var removeButton = $("<button class='removeButton'>X</button>");
    removeButton.on("click", function() {
      var textDiv = $(this).parent();
      var prevDiv = textDiv.prevAll(".textDiv").first();
      var nextDiv = textDiv.nextAll(".textDiv").first();
      textDiv.remove();
      if (nextDiv.length) {
        $(".textInput").css({
          top: nextDiv.position().top,
          left: nextDiv.position().left
        });
      } else if (prevDiv.length) {
        $(".textInput").css({
          top: prevDiv.position().top + prevDiv.outerHeight() + 2,
          left: prevDiv.position().left
        });
      } else {
        $(".textInput").css({
          top: $(".container").position().top,
          left: $(".container").position().left
        });
      }
      $(".textInput").prop("disabled", false);
    });
    textDiv.append(removeButton);
    var prevDiv = textDiv.prevAll(".textDiv").first();
    if (prevDiv.length) {
      textDiv.css({
        top: prevDiv.position().top + prevDiv.outerHeight() + 2,
        left: prevDiv.position().left
      });
    } else {
      textDiv.css({
        top: $(".textInput").position().top,
        left: $(".textInput").position().left
      });
    }
    $(".container").append(textDiv);
    $(".textInput").val("");
    $(".textInput").css({
      top: textDiv.position().top + textDiv.outerHeight() + 2,
      left: textDiv.position().left
    });
    $(".textInput").prop("disabled", false);
  }
}

// Listen for keydown events on the textInput
$(".textInput").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 188) {
    e.preventDefault();
    createTextDiv($(this).val());
  } else if (e.keyCode == 8 && $(this).val().length == 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lastDiv = $(".textDiv").last();
    if (lastDiv.length) {
      $(".textInput").css({
        top: lastDiv.position().top,
        left: lastDiv.position().left
      });
    }
    lastDiv.remove();
    $(".textInput").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});

// Listen for paste events on the container
$(".container").on("paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pastedText = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text");
  var lines = pastedText.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    createTextDiv(lines[i]);
  }
});

// Enable typing on textInput when a new textDiv is created
$(".container").on("DOMNodeInserted", ".textDiv", function() {
  $(".textInput").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: #ccc #f5f5f5;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.textDiv {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #E1ECF4;
  border: 1px solid #B0CBE3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  max-width: 95%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: default;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.removeButton {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.removeButton:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.textInput {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <textarea class="textInput"></textarea>
</div>
```

Kindly help me make the necessary changes so that every time I delete a text div from the top or the middle, the divs below it should automatically adjust their position. Thanks!

**P.S
If you didn't get what I meant, you can run the snippet, create 4-5 text divs and check the problem yourself.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm being honest here: I couldn't figure out exactly what is wrong with your code although I tried to analyze it. I assume, that there is something wrong with your calculations. I would suggest, that you console.log the calculated values for each step to get to the problem.

To offer some help, I refactored your removeButton-function, so that it is working (as far as I understood your requirement):

```
removeButton.on("click", function () {
    var textDiv = $(this).parent();
    textDiv.remove();
    $(".textDiv").each((index, element) => {
        //recalculate Top-position of all textDivs
        $(element).css({
            // remove units from Top-Property to add outerHeight-value, then add px for correct CSS-value
            top: (index === 0 ? 0 : parseInt($(element).prev().css("top")) + $(element).prev().outerHeight() + 2) + "px",
            left: 0,
        });
    });
    $(".textInput").css({
        top: $(".textDiv").toArray().length === 0 ? 0 : parseInt($(".textDiv").last().css("top")) + $(".textDiv").last().outerHeight() + 2 + "px",
        left: 0,
    });
    $(".textInput").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

**Explanation:**
The function is now always recalculating every top-position of every textDiv and therefor is looping through an array of all textDivs remaining on the page after removing one.
It is important to note, that the Top-Property has to be parsed as Integer to remove the unit ("px"). Otherwise there is no way to add the value to the outerHeight()-value. After this is done, the "px" is added again.
For further refactoring I would advise to create a separate function to calculate the Top-values, so that there is no redundant code for .textDiv and .textInput.

Hope this helps!

## **Alternative solution:**

You can achieve a similar behaviour with CSS flexbox and the Order-Property. You won't need ANY position calculations this way.

**CSS-Code:**

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: #ccc #f5f5f5;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: "flex-start";
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.textDiv {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #e1ecf4;
    border: 1px solid #b0cbe3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    max-width: 95%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    line-height: 1.5;
    cursor: default;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    order: 0;
}

.removeButton {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.removeButton:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.textInput {
    display: block;
    order: 1;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

**JavaScript-Code:**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Function to create a new textDiv and add it to the container
            function createTextDiv(text) {
                if (text.trim() != "") {
                    var textDiv = $("<div class='textDiv'></div>").text(
                        text.trim()
                    );
                    var removeButton = $(
                        "<button class='removeButton'>X</button>"
                    );
                    removeButton.on("click", function () {
                        var textDiv = $(this).parent();
                        textDiv.remove();
                    });
                    textDiv.append(removeButton);
                    $(".container").append(textDiv);
                    // the following calculation is widening the margin to create only one textDiv per line - remove this for normal FlexBox-behaviour
                    textDiv.css("margin-right", $(".container").width() * (parseInt(textDiv.css("max-width")) / 100) - textDiv.width() + "px");
                    $(".textInput").val("");
                    $(".textInput").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            }

            // Listen for keydown events on the textInput
            $(".textInput").on("keydown", function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 188) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    createTextDiv($(this).val());
                } else if (e.keyCode == 8 && $(this).val().length == 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var lastDiv = $(".textDiv").last();
                    lastDiv.remove();
                    $(".textInput").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });

            // Listen for paste events on the container
            $(".container").on("paste", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var pastedText =
                    e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text");
                var lines = pastedText.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
                for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    createTextDiv(lines[i]);
                }
            });

            // Enable typing on textInput when a new textDiv is created
            $(".container").on("DOMNodeInserted", ".textDiv", function () {
                $(".textInput").prop("disabled", false);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Of course, this is your decision, but from my point of view, this is much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Although it's creating divs horizontally, I guess we'll need a little change to create them vertically.

Comment: With FlexBox, the space is always distributed in the most efficient way, so as long as boxes are small enough to fit horizontally, they will stand next to each other (but this will be responsive, so that the boxes rearrange on smaller screens). If you absolutely need every TextDiv in a single line because of design decisions, please use the Javascript-solution I provided in the first part of my answer. // Side note: there are ways to get this behaviour with FlexBox, but these are also kind of "hacks".

Comment: Well, to complete this: I added a calculation to the Javascript-Code of the Alternative Solution, so that the remaining white-space of each line is filled by the margin of the TextDiv. This way, you will always have only one TextDiv per Line. However, this is a hack and I do NOT recommend this from a webdesign perspective.